# Working fine in IE but not in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

Here is my design

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="divheader"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftsection"></div>
    <div id="middlesection"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   height: 90%;
}
#divheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;        
}
#leftsection {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;    
    flex-align: baseline;
}
#middlesection {
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;        
}
```

It is working fine with IE 11.0 but page is showing vertical scroll in Chrome and Firefox.

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: This is working fine in my chrome and firefox browser without scrollbar

Comment: Is `flex-align` a thing any more..if ever?

Comment: Is IE a thing anymore?

Comment: @Paulie_D may be "align-items"

Comment: Sure...if this was flexbox...but the OP is using floats.

Comment: @DelightedD0D You can't ignore IE

Comment: We are focusing on IE and Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @akash sorry, that was a joke. Of course I give IE all the attention it warrants...

Comment: Any suggestions, why I am getting the scroll ?

Comment: Honestly, Im not entirely clear what your issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong here, but from what I am seeing here is that you are trying to use flex-align, I might be wrong but I do not think this exists.

align-items use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and removes the need of floats (the sole purpose of using flex, so you do not have to break the flow of the page.)

if you are using flex indeed you need to "activate" it by using, display:flex within the wrapper, then any child of that container is based on flex.

```
#leftsection {
   display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
   display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
   display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
   display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
   display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

   /* What type of direction would you want the wrapper to be -> <- down or up */
   /* here we say make the direction of the primary axis down (from top to bottom) */       
   -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
   -moz-flex-flow: column nowrap;
   -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
   flex-flow: column nowrap;

   /* here we define the positioning of the elements inside the container to the center (in the primary axis) (This will center the items from top and bottom */
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   -moz-justify-content: center;
   -ms-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;

   /* after that you may use align-items. however align-tems is based on cross axis positioning, so if you want the children to be on the left side you should use this: */
   -webkit-align-items: flext-start;
   -moz-align-items: flex-start;
   -ms-align-items: flex-start;
   align-items: flex-start;

   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;
   width: 10%;
}
```

With this any element added into the #leftsection will be on the center of the column and on the left side of the column (positioning).

Hope this helps you mate, or I just wrote complete nonsense nothing that will help you with your issue ^^.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation. I am working on your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Is that something similar to your idea? Please tell us what exactly do you need :)

```
#wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height:40px;
    }

    #divheader {
        width: 75%;
        height: 10%;        
        border:1px solid black;
        text-align:  center;
        background-color:orange;
    }
    #leftsection {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;
        width:10%;
        height:120px;
        display:inline-block;  
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color:skyblue;
    }
    #middlesection {
        width: 65%;
        height:120px;
        display:inline-block;
        border:1px solid black;        
        margin-left:0%;
        background-color:red;
    }
```